# Точки перед картинками соцсетей блока "Поделиться" яндекс

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

доброго времени суток!

Не подскажете, почему перед иконками соцсетей отображаются значки элементов списка (li - точка)? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Адрес сайта - http://alfglobal.ru/balashiha.php

Comment: смотрите `template.css` в районе `.column ul li { ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Маркеры списка заданы через `background` в `.column ul li`.

Добавьте в `.ya-share2__list_direction_horizontal > .ya-share2__item` `background: none;`.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте поставить свойство `list-style-image: none;` после объявления элемента...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: к сожалению, не помогает((. правда на сервер не выкладывал, пробую на домашнем компе.